# Creating nonclassical shape in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to replicate the attached figure using tikzpicture latex, for the circle and the text it is easy but for the shapes in blue, I would appreciate the help.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer below uses the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

The icons are from the [fontawesome5](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5) package.

The gaps between the slices are obtained with the key `gap`.

The shape of the slices is determined by the key `slices inner arc tangent`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\wheelchart[
  data=,
  gap=0.1,
  middle=Six Positioning\\Technology Trends\\Toward 6G,
  radius={2.5}{4},
  slices inner arc tangent,
  slices style=blue!40!black,
  value=1,
  wheel data={\LARGE\WCvarA}\\\WCvarB,
  wheel data pos=0.3,
  wheel data style={white,align=center}
]{%
  \faStopwatch/Low cost \&\\Low complexity,
  \faIndustry/High\\accuracy,
  \faDollyFlatbed/Low latency,
  \faCarSide/Sidelink,
  \faCloud/Architecture\\evolution,
  \faGlasses/Beyond\\connectivity%
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) circle[radius=2];
\foreach \i in {0,...,5}{
\fill[blue!40!black, rotate=\i*360/6] 
($ (-30:3) +(60:0.05) $) -- ($ (-30:1) +(60:0.05) $) 
to[out=150, in=210] 
($ (30:1) +(-60:0.05) $) -- ($ (30:3) +(-60:0.05) $)
-- cycle;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Circle with six colored sections]

Answer (score 3):

Just to start:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) circle(5.5);
            \foreach \a in {30,90,...,270,330}
                \fill[cyan] plot[domain=-3:3, smooth, rotate=\a] (\x,{.4*\x*\x+2});
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

**EDIT**: More complete code (sorry I dont have graphical icons).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) circle(5.5);
            \foreach \a in {30,90,...,270,330}
                \fill[cyan] plot[domain=-3:3, smooth, rotate=\a] (\x,{.4*\x*\x+2});
        \end{scope}
            \node[align=center] at (0,0) () {\large \bfseries Six Positioning\\ \bfseries Technology Trends\\\large \bfseries Toward 6G};
            \node[align=center,white] at (4,.2) () {\large \bfseries High\\\large \bfseries accuracy};
            \node[align=center,white] at (2.2,3) () {\large \bfseries Low cost \&\\\large \bfseries Low complexity};
            \node[align=center,white] at (-2.2,3) () {\large \bfseries Beyond\\\large \bfseries connectivity};
            \node[align=center,white] at (-4,.2) () {\large \bfseries Architecture\\\large \bfseries evolution};
            \node[align=center,white] at (-2.2,-3) () {\large \bfseries Sidelink};
            \node[align=center,white] at (2.2,-3) () {\large \bfseries Low latency};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:[image]